# Trouble managing ActionBarSherlok and backcompatibility

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm extending `SherlockFragmentActivity`. When I inspect the element `this.getFragmentManager()` I obtain the following description.

```
FragmentManager android.app.Activity.getFragmentManager()

public FragmentManager getFragmentManager () 
Added in API level 11
Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this activity.
```

This means that I can use it only for API level 11 or more.

In fact the following code give me an error:

```
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getFragmentManager();
android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
DetailsServiceListFragment fragment = new DetailsServiceListFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.dettservizio,fragment);
```

where `DetailsServiceListFragment` extends `SherlockListFragment`

The error is on the fourth line, and says:

```
The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, DetailsServiceListFragment)
```

This happens because DetailsServiceListFragment need to extend Fragment. But why I can't extend `SherlockListFragment`?

When I use the classes included in Sherlok project what Fragment I have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `getSupportFragmentManager()` method instead. The `android.app.*` Fragment related classes are only for API 11+, like you noted.

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
DetailsServiceListFragment fragment = new DetailsServiceListFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.dettservizio,fragment);
```

Also, don't forget to commit your `FragmentTransaction`

```
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

`DetailsServiceListFragment extends SherlockListFragment`, and `SherlockListFragment` already extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, so that is fine,keep it as is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the support library version of the `Fragment` (i.e.     `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`) alongside `getSupporFragmentManager()`. If you want, you can now use Android's own backport of the ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, I would suggest using the ActionBarCompat library (which is part of the official Google Support library - Version 7).

It took them a long time to create an Actionbar that is backwards compatible, but now that it exists, you should use it instead of ActionBarSherlock.

Here is the API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html

...and a good intro: https://plus.google.com/108967384991768947849/posts/9Tw5zZvAGnq